# why are buttons white in colour when I have added background_normal:somepngfile.png which has dark blue colour?

Tags: python, kivy

I am making an app in which I want the buttons on the main page should have blue colour. for that I have used background_normal:'somepngfile.png'. But when I run the code It is completely white in colour. what could be the problem? why its white and how can I correct it?

```
            <MenuPage>:
        Image:
            size_hint:.90,.10
            source:'BackBlue.png'
        Label: 
            text: "Vocabulary Journal"
            size_hint: .90,.10

        StackLayout:
            orientation: 'tb-rl'
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10

            Button:
                text: 'Search'
                size_hint: None,.20
                width: 130
                background_down:'BlueShadeDot.png'
                background_normal: 'NightSky.png'
                on_press: root.manager.current='display'
            Button:
                text: 'New Word'
                size_hint: None,.20
                width: 130
                background_down:'BlueShadeDot.png'
                background_normal: 'NightSky.png'
                on_press: root.manager.current='newword'
            Button:
                text: 'Flash Cards'
                size_hint: None,.20
                width: 130
                background_down:'BlueShadeDot.png'
                background_normal: 'NightSky.png'
                on_press: root.manager.current='flashcard'
                on_release:FlashCard.Iterate_buttons()

            Button:
                text: 'Word Groups'
                size_hint: None,.20
                width: 130
                background_down:'BlueShadeDot.png'
                background_normal: 'NightSky.png'
                on_press: root.manager.current='wordgroup'
```

the image which I am using is

[image]

but the buttons are  completely white

Comment: you can work a little and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Is 'NightSky.png' in the same directory as your script? That happens when the file can't be found...